# How to register the data verificiation udf for multiple nodes in cluster version of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I try to use the data verification function in the query statement of Apache IoTDB, for example `select iqr(column1) from root.test`, it shows that this function has not been registered. I saw a `udf library` package when I downloaded the install package, but I don’t know where to put it to register this UDF? And also after I run the register script on one node, do other nodes have to run it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this udf library under the `ext/udf` directory of Apache IoTDB, and your udf should be able to execute after you run the register script. And yes, when you need to execute the udf on other nodes, you need to run the register process again.